# iptables doesn't forward from WAN to virtual machines

Tags: iptables

I have a machine working like gateway and have two network interfaces:

- `eth0` LAN : 192.168.1.0/24
- `eth1` WAN : `XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX` (my public ip)

This machine has 3 VM guest over virtualbox. All have bridged network and have static IP given by our DNS.

I have the following iptables

```
*filter
    -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Rules a webserver VM
*nat
    -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
    -A PREROUTING -d XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/32 -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.100
    -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.100/32  -j SNAT --to-source XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

I can access the VMs from my LAN, but when I try to access them from the WAN it doesn't work. What is wrong?

Comment: I assumed `eht0` and `eht1` were typos for `eth0` and `eth1` respectively.

Comment: Does the virtual machine know the "route" map to reply to WAN machines?
Please check default router of your virtual machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it correct to assume that the default policy for FORWARD in the filter table is DROP?  (If not, those two filter rules would be pointless because you're accepting everything anyways.)

If that assumption is correct, then your problem is that you're lacking an ACCEPT rule for forwarding new packets to the VM.  Add this rule:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -p tcp -d 192.168.1.100 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

By the way, the SNAT rule for packets from the VM is redundant - you're already masquerading all packets going out over eth1.

Comment: the default policity for `FORWARD` is `ACCEPT`

Comment: i need the SNAT rule cos i have a squid but is not relevant in this case

Comment: have you posted your complete iptables ruleset?  What's the output of `iptables-save`?

Comment: yeah is a complete ruleset